# Automatically tidying up GAE cron backups

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm running the standard cron job to backup my GAE Datastore every night to a Google Storage bucket. I've added the code to tidy this up and delete old backups in the bucket as I only need the last week of backups:

```
    GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();

    // Today, and 3 days before date
    Date today = new Date();
    Date Lastweek = new Date();
    Long LastweekMS = today.getTime() - (7*24*60*60*1000);
    Lastweek.setTime(LastweekMS);

    try{
        ListResult list = gcsService.list(bucket, new ListOptions.Builder().setRecursive(true).build());

        while(list.hasNext()){
            ListItem item = list.next();
            if(item.getLastModified().after(Lastweek) == false)
            {
                gcsService.delete(new GcsFilename(bucket, item.getName()));
            }
        }
    }
```

This works very nicely. However, is there an API to also delete the entries in the Datastore Admin. While they don't cost me anything I'd rather make them match what is in the Storage bucket. (and I don't want to use the GUI :-)

Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 2):

State information for Datastore backups is stored in entities in Datastore itself.

For completed jobs, you can delete entities that match the query:

```
SELECT * FROM _AE_DatastoreAdmin_Operation
WHERE status = "Completed"
AND last_updated < DATETIME("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSSSSS+zz:ZZ")
```

Note that in order to run the query, you'll need to create an index on the kind first:

```
indexes:
- kind: _AE_DatastoreAdmin_Operation
  ancestor: no
  properties:
  - name: status
  - name: last_updated
    direction: desc
```

And, as an alternative to using AE cron, you can use GCS's lifecycle management to auto-delete objects older than N days: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle